# how to cpu mine on arch linux after installing monero-v0.10.3.1?

Tags: cpu-mining

I use Arch Linux and installed monero-v0.10.3.1, started monerod and also created a wallet.

How can I start CPU mining?

Do I need additional tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the monero daemon (monerod) and type `start_mining` followed by your wallet address and then the number of threads.

For example:

```
start_mining 44AFFq5kSiGBoZ4NMDwYtN18obc8AemS33DBLWs3H7otXft3XjrpDtQGv7SqSsaBYBb98uNbr2VBBEt7f2wfn3RVGQBEP3A 4
```

This would start mining with 4 threads to the monero donation address. However this is solo-mining and it is unlikely unless you have high hashrates to actually find a block so I would recommend you join a pool.

A list of pools can be found here:

http://moneropools.com/

http://chainradar.com/xmr/pools

And a guide to mining to pools can be found here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/wiki/index

https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/guides/how-to-mine-monero/

It should be noted that mining to a pool requires additional software:

[Confusion over Monero Mining Software](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3631/confusion-over-monero-mining-software)

https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/wiki/index/windows-pool

Answer (score 1):

I am on Fedora, but things shouldn't be too different. If you want to mine for a pool, rather than solo-mining, you should install additional software.

[XMR-stak-cpu](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-cpu) - or the correspondent for AMD GPU and Nvidia GPU - is probably the best choice if you have a relatively new processor.

```
git clone git@github.com:fireice-uk/xmr-stak-cpu.git
cd xmr-stak-cpu
cmake .
make install
cd bin
```

You will probably need to install some libraries such as `libmicrohttpd-devel` and `hwloc-devel` before running cmake.

Then edit the config.txt file with the instructions provided by the mining pool of your choice

```
gedit config.txt
```

And finally start mining

```
./xmr-stak-cpu
```

For alternative instructions for Linux, and links to some pools, see also this page on [Monero How](https://www.monero.how/tutorial-how-to-mine-monero).

Consider that for Monero eco-system it is better to prevent excessive centralization in big pools, so you may want to join a medium-sized or relatively small pool.